# Why does .pre in mongoose prevents accessing the record until next run?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

recently I have been testing mongoose with nodejs, and I am a little confuse on the behavior of the following code

In user-db

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    bcrypt = require('bcrypt'),
    SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true, index: {unique: true}},
    password: {type: String, required: true}
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    var user = this;
    // only hash the password if it has been modified (or is newly created)
    if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();
    //generate a salt
    bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt){
        if (err) return next(err);
        // hash the password along with our new salt
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash){
            if(err) return next(err);
            // override the cleartext password with the hashed one
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
   });
});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb){
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch){
        if (err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

In user-server

```
var = User = require('./user-db.js');

function test_save(data){
    var compare = new User({
        username: 'compare3',
        password: 'compare3'
    });

    compare.save(function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
    });

    User.findOne({username: 'compare3'}, function(err, user){
        if (err) throw err;

        if (user){
            console.log("you find compare 3");
        }
    });
```

Here is the behavior:

If I want to print

"you find compare3"

I have to run my app.js once, turn off the app.js using control-C and then run it again, the first time value for user is null

Why is that? I assume .pre doesn't work as I wanted to, although I thought the next() has fixed that issue?

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called a ["callback"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29).

You code is not executing in a "linear" fashion so it **does not** *"wait"* until the `.save()` completes.

This is why all the functions have "callback"" methods. So **that** code inside them is called when the operation completes:

You code needs to "inside" this, as in:

```
    compare.save(function(err){
        if (err) throw err;

        User.findOne({username: 'compare3'}, function(err, user){
            if (err) throw err;

            if (user){
                console.log("you find compare 3");
            }
        });
    });
```

Then the find is performed **after** the document is saved. Before it was likely not saved yet.

If you are going to be working with Node.js then you need to expand your understanding of [event loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) and related styles in creating "non-blocking" programs. Try searching on those terms and you should find plenty of information.